# Run batch on Windows to copy folder from linuxserver to linuxserver

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy, network-drive

### Setup:

I have two linux server and on both I shared a folder.
Server 1 is for saving and editing files and the second is for the backup.
Then I have a Windows 10 workstation on which I mounted both of the shared folders.

### Goal:

I would like to run a batch file on my Windows 10 Workstation with which I can copy a folder (it‘s content) from one linux server to the other.

I've been trying hard since days but it didn't want to work.

### Folder structure:

**Server 1:**

/data/ictproject/[here are the files and folders I want to copy]

The folder "ictproject" is shared.

**Server 2:**

/backup/[here is the destination]

The folder "backup" is shared.

**D:\ on Windows 10**

D:\backup[temporary destination]

#### First try:

```
@echo off

Xcopy "\\[IP-Adress-Server-1]\data\ictproject" "\\[IP-Adress-Server-2]\backup\ict_%data%" /E

pause 0
```

#### Second try:

```
@echo off

Xcopy "\\[IP-Adress-Server-1]\data\ictproject" "D:\backup\ict_%date%\" /E
Xcopy "D:\backup\ict_%date%\" "\\[IP-Adress-Server-2]\backup\ict_%data%\" /E

pause 0
```

I also tried the hole thing with copy and plenty other things instead of Xcopy but I didn't try robocopy which actualy is the newer version.(I just got to know that seconds ago)

Comment: Does XCopy give an error message?

Comment: Cross site duplicate: https://superuser.com/q/763340/105621

Comment: In what way did you mount the Linux storage to Windows? Are you running Samba on Linux?

Comment: Xcopy says username or password incorrect and yes i mounted it with samba

Comment: Oh and by the way the server 1 is mapped as I:\ and server 2  as b:\ on my windows 10 workstation just if that matters